Azure Devops Pipeline, show link do Sonar report on the summary page of Pipeline Run
I have a Azure Devos Pipeline, which in one of the stages is running Sonar report. After runnig the Pipeline summary page looks like:

I would like to include the Sonar report link on this first page somewhere (in Jenkins I was able to have the link on the left menu, easy reachable after each job run)
What I have to do now in order to find the link is to go inside the specific stage, find the job which is runnig the report, go to the logs and find the link there:

Is there a way to either add the link somewhere on summary tab, or add additional tab with a link for Azure Pipeline?

You can use SonarQubePublish@6 (SonarQube) or the SonarCloudPublish@2 (SonarCloud) tasks to publish quality gate result.
After running the pipeline you should find a link to the analysis report in Build Summary > Extensions tab:

See Driving continuous quality of your code with SonarCloud for more details.

this looks like something I am looking for, I will try it

Apparently my setup for sonar report is not the simplest one, I have created another question in order to figure out how to run  SonarQubePublish@6 in my pipeline: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78719387/sonarqubepublish6-fails-when-running-from-another-stage-than-sonarqubeprepare

@fascynacja if I were you I would copy/paste the templates you mentioned in the other question into your repository and add the SonarQubePublish@6 (SonarQube) or the SonarCloudPublish@2 (SonarCloud) tasks, just to see if it works or not. When these tasks are added to the shared templates you can easily change your pipeline to reference it.
