SonarQubePublish@6 fails when running from another stage than SonarQubePrepare, saying: "Variables are missing"
I am working on a Dev Azure pipeline which is runnig couple of stages which have tasks for preparing sonar report. The important parts of stages which I want to focus on look like:
build_and_sonar_prepare:
    - task: SonarQubePrepare@6
      displayName: prepare_sonar
      inputs:
        SonarQube: ${{ parameters.SonarQube}}
        scannerMode: 'Other'
        
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: scan_sonar
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          mvn sonar:sonar other commands
        
sonar_publish:
     - task: SonarQubePublish@6
       inputs:
       pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

The build_and_sonar_prepare is not managed by me, its part of a template which I am reusing. It runs fine and generates proper sonar report with a link to sonar server.
The stage which I have controll is sonar_publish, where I would like to only publish the results in order to see the results of the report in Azure Devops Pipeline summary (I have created separate question for that: (Azure Devops Pipeline, show link do Sonar report on the summary page of Pipeline Run)
What happens here is

SonarQubePrepare is being called with a proper working connection to SonarQube ${{ parameters.SonarQube}}, which is managed by Azure and its working fine.
the mvn sonar:sonar  is being called, instead of SonarCubeAnalyze and unfortunately I cannot change it, because its part of the template
SonarQubePublish@6 is being called, but from another stage

After I run this pipeline I am getting an error:
 ##[error]Variables are missing. Please make sure that you are running the Prepare and Analyze tasks before running the Publish task.
I have tried to put the SonarCubeAnalyze  in my stage, before I call Publish but it also failed. I have also ensured that all files generated by sonar report are copied in the workspace of sonar_publish (using CopyFiles@2 and PublishBuildArtifacts@1 in the build_and_sonar_prepare stage and  CopyFiles@2 in the sonar_publish stage)
So far without success.
I wonder if it is possible to Publish sonar report with this setup?
I also would like to know which variables are missing and how to check if they exist in the sonar_publish stage and what are their values?

The easiest and logical thing to do here is to ask whoever is managing the build_and_sonar_prepare template(s) to add a new task. If the author is worried about breaking or somehow changing the behaviour of existing builds, he/she can add a boolean parameter named publishQualityGate with default value false and based on that parameter include the task or not.

Or, as an alternative, add pre and post steps to the stage or job templates - see Create Configurable and Extensible Jobs

adding the conditional runnig of this task is something I will propose to the owners of the templates, in the meantime I am still trying to configure it somehow in my own stage

You must put SonarQubePrepare@6 task and SonarQubePublish@6 task in the same job.
I can reproduce your issue when putting SonarQubePrepare@6 task and SonarQubePublish@6 task in the different jobs.

SonarQubePrepare@6 task is used to configure all the required settings before executing the build. This task is mandatory and the scope is the current job. When running the "sonar_publish" stage, it will run on a brand-new agent which hasn't been configured with SonarQube. This agent doesn't contain any info you have configured in "build_and_sonar_prepare" stage. As shown in the screenshot, the values ​​of SONARQUBE_SCANNER_PARAMS and SONAR_ENDPOINT are both "undefined".
If you check the debug log of a working run (In the same job), you can see that the SonarQubePublish@6 task will automatically get information from the current environment.

If you can't add SonarQubePublish@6 task to "build_and_sonar_prepare" stage, you can add SonarQubePrepare@6 task to your "sonar_publish" stage and use the same service connection.
Some docs for your reference:

Agent pool jobs.
SonarQube & Azure DevOps integration.


Update:
If you can't put SonarQubePrepare@6 task and SonarQubePublish@6 task in the same job. You can parse the log to get the result URL and put it to the build summary page.

Run REST API to get the log id of task SonarQubeAnalyze@6 and use this id to get the task log.
Parse the log and get the result URL. Write the URL into a Markdown file.
Using logging command ##vso[task.uploadsummary] to upload result URL to the build summary page via a summary Markdown file.

PowerShell Task
Refer to the following PowerShell scripts:
- job: JobB
  dependsOn: JobA
  steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $token = "$(PAT)"
          $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
          $head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
          $org = "{OrgName}"
          $proj = "{ProjectName}"
          $url1 ="https://dev.azure.com/$org/$proj/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/timeline?api-version=6.0"
          $timeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Method Get -Headers $head 
          $targetlog = $timeline.records | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "SonarQubeAnalyze"} | Select-Object 
          $logId = $targetlog.log.id
          $logId
          
          
          $url2 = "https://dev.azure.com/$org/$proj/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/logs/$($logId)?api-version=6.0"
          $logContent = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Method Get -Headers $head 
          $logLines = $logContent -split "`n"
          $targetline = $logLines | Select-String -Pattern "ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can find the results at:"
          Write-Output $targetline
          $sonarUrl = $targetline.Line
          $sonarUrl = $sonarUrl.Split("ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL", 2)[1]
          $sonarUrl
          $sonarUrl | Out-File -FilePath Summary.md -Encoding utf8
          Write-Host "##vso[task.uploadsummary]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Summary.md"


Result:

Bash task
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          token="$(PAT)"
          token=$(echo -n ":${token}" | base64)
          head="Authorization: Basic ${token}"
          org="{OrgName}"
          proj="{ProjectName}"
          url1="https://dev.azure.com/${org}/${proj}/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/timeline?api-version=6.0"
          
          timeline=$(curl -s -H "${head}" "${url1}")
          targetlog=$(echo "${timeline}" | jq '.records[] | select(.name=="SonarQubeAnalyze")')
          logId=$(echo "${targetlog}" | jq '.log.id')
          
          url2="https://dev.azure.com/${org}/${proj}/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)/logs/${logId}?api-version=6.0"
          logContent=$(curl -s -H "${head}" "${url2}")
          targetline=$(echo "${logContent}" | grep "ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can find the results at:")
          sonarUrl=$(echo "${targetline}" | cut -d' ' -f5-)
          
          echo "${sonarUrl}" > Summary.md
          echo "##vso[task.uploadsummary]$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Summary.md"

I am testing using SonarCloud, so the URL is different.

I will try this approach., In the meantime, where in the documentation is states that those tasks have to be run from the same job? I found some info that those can be run even from different stages.

I have tried your solution, indeed I do not have error now but I have a warning: ##[warning]No analyses found in this build! Please check your build configuration..  Also in the "SonarQube Analysis Report" panel I do not see any data.

"where in the documentation is states that those tasks have to be run from the same job" - As I mentioned above, SonarQubePrepare@6 task is used to configured with SonarQube for the current job. When running "sonar_publish" stage, it will run on a fresh agent, where the agent hasn't been configured to access your SonarQube. This is how an agent job works. See more info about agent job see Agent pool jobs.

"but I have a warning: ##[warning]No analyses found in this build! Please check your build configuration." You see this warning because you didn't do any analyses in "sonar_publish" stage.

"I have also ensured that all files generated by sonar report are copied in the workspace of sonar_publish (using CopyFiles@2 and PublishBuildArtifacts@1 in the build_and_sonar_prepare stage" - You can add  CopyFiles@2 and PublishBuildArtifacts@1 to "build_and_sonar_prepare" stage, why you can't add a SonarQubePublish@6 task to this stage? It would be easier than adding SonarQubePrepare@6 task and doing analyses in your "sonar_publish" stage.

those two tasks are already included in build_and_sonar_prepare stage. I did not add them to be honest they are already there

For your question in this ticket, there is no way to make SonarQubePublish@6 task working without adding SonarQubePrepare@6 task and doing analyses in the same job. This is how SonarQube extension and DevOps agent job work.

May I know what's the report URL in your this question? I want to know the format without knowing the specific parameters. Is it something like https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id={SonarQubeProjectId}? Then I can try to help you show link of URL in the summary page using other ways.

The link is like : https://sonar.domain.interna.company.int/v9/dashboard?id=eeee&branch=rrrr

If you can't put SonarQubePrepare@6 task and SonarQubePublish@6 task in the same job. You can parse the log to get the result URL and put it to the build summary page. See my update above for the details.

That looks amazing, I will try it out

unfortunately it looks like the agents do not have powershell:( I am getting error: ##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'pwsh'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.

You can install PowerShell on your machine. If you can't, you can adjust the scripts to the one supported on your machine. The scripts above just run two REST API, find the target string in the log and run logging command ##vso[task.uploadsummary].

I do not have the rights to update the agents I will try to request it to the devops team. I was usinb only Bash tasks so far

I have updated the Answer above with Bash task. Please try it in your pipeline. Please replace OrgName and ProjectName with your actual value. Create a PAT and add it to the pipeline as a variable. It's suggested to set the scope to FULL for test to avoid insufficient permissions.

The solution with bash worked as expected. After I will get the agent updated I will also try the option with powershell

So is the conclusion that we can save the variables that the SonarqubePrepare defines (via markdown or using build variables) and then use them in another job? Your comment suggests we could not, but I don't understand what the prepare job does that we cannot 'move' to another job?

@Roelant, "So is the conclusion that we can save the variables that the SonarqubePrepare defines (via markdown or using build variables) and then use them in another job" - No.  As I mentioned, "You must put SonarQubePrepare@6 task and SonarQubePublish@6 task in the same job." See this for the details.

The question of fascynacja is to put the result URL to the build summary page. The result URL is parsed from build log in another job since he can't change the original job. The result URL is not used for another job.

Thanks for your quick reply. In the details you provide you only mention the two environment variables - for those we can of course do some magic to lift those to another job. So I was wondering if you knew what else is configured :)
